# after using drop method rows appear in my plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using drop method for rows in my Dataframe. After I drop some rows (bedrooms == [0, 33]) I don't see these rows when I print them. However, I use the seaborn countplot and [0, 33] appear on the plot. The problem is on the screenshot below.

```
print(df.query('bedrooms == [0, 33]').head()) #check before dropping rows
```

output:
it shows rows assosiated with bedrooms == [0, 33]

```
df.drop(df.query('bedrooms == [0, 33]').index, axis = 0, inplace = True)
#Test
print(df.query('bedrooms == [0, 33]'))

sb.countplot(data = df, x = 'bedrooms', hue = 'grade', palette = 'Blues');
```

output: as it is on the screenshort it shows 0 and 33

Why these rows appear on the plot?
Thank you!

[screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZuQ6.jpg)

Comment: You did not include the screenshot, and please provide code instead of/with screenshots.

Comment: Please share the code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Without the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to provide solution. One thing you can do as a hack is to use `plt.xlim(1, 10)` or something like this to restrict your x-axis

Comment: @Bazingaa, yes it is possible, but why it is still in the dataframe after I drop it?

Comment: Try assigning the date frame to new variable

Comment: @Bazingaa is right, if you do not assign the new `df` to a  variable, it will not be updated. Something like `df2 = df.drop(df.query('bedrooms == [0, 33]')` and then plotting `df2` will work

Comment: Thanks, it works. But still, it is strange that 
print(df.query('bedrooms == [0, 33]')) does not show these values, but they only appear on the histogram....